Can I make my circuit ‘sleep’?
Can a phototransistor be used to open circuit a power rail so circuit is only active during daylight hours?

Yes, it certainly can but, it might be more appropriate to user a timer because of the effects of clouds, fog, rain, mist, eclipses etc..

Yes indeed, there are likely billions of devices operating like this already, so it certainly is possible. Without details though, we can't offer a better answer than simple "yes", so edit in what you want to really ask.

What if there is a spurious light that is flashed on the phototransistor? You need to think of such cases also.... Though your idea can work, you have to think of all possible pitfalls like what others have mentioned.


Can a phototransistor be used to open circuit a power rail so circuit is only active during daylight hours?

On its own? No. The gradual turn-on as the light level increased and decreased would cause the power rail voltage to rise and fall slowly. The phototransistor would also dissipate a lot of power and probably burn out.
A web search for "automatic light level switch schematic" should turn up many suggestions using phototransistors or light-dependent resistors to drive other more powerful components to switch the power on and off cleanly.

Judging by your username, I guess you speak with good authority on this subject.

What I find a little disappointing in this answer is that is in essence a call to search the internet. Could you elevate the answer by perhaps including some examples links? If a web search “ should turn up many suggestions using phototransistors or light-dependent resistors to drive other more powerful components to switch the power on and off cleanly” it should not be too difficult to curate rather than leaving the OP to stumble on something incorrect or potentially unsafe?

@fdcpp, what I found disappointing about the question was the lack of detail about the supply and load. There wasn't any point in me doing a load of work with most of it being useless to the OP. Thanks for the feedback though.

In that case I would suggest you  don’t answer or take your opportunity to be an educator and add the missing detail.

@fdcpp, sorry, but I answered the actual question asked and gave a pointer on the OP's next step. I've done many, many hours of education on this site.

I appreciate and accept the answer given - the way I asked the question was indeed pretty vague and the response was helpful and gave me a start on next steps to pursue.  I wasnt entirely sure how to phrase the question to be honest as not familiar with the various approaches or technologies.

Yes, clock gating and power gating are used to put (integrated) circuits to sleep. They are classic techniques for dynamic power management in digital circuits and electronic systems, including the VLSI implementation of processor architectures. They also work for mixed-signal integrated circuits (ICs). A similar technique to power gating can be implemented for analog circuits.
By analogy, you can use photodiodes for "light gating," by putting the circuit to sleep when there is not enough light.
I have not come across the term "phototransistors," though.

There's a summary on phototransistors at the bottom of https://www.digikey.ie/en/articles/the-basics-of-photodiodes-and-phototransistors-and-how-to-apply-them. All transistors are phototransistors until they're encapsulated in an opaque material. A couple of times that I've needed a phototransistor I file the top off a BC108 metal can type and it works!

@Transistor, thank you for the information. I have not come across this in my undergraduate textbooks, and my graduate coursework focus on electronic design automation, and adjacent areas, like VLSI design, mathematical optimization, decision procedures (a subset of automated reasoning, and logical AI), machine learning, and computer architecture.

Thanks for the responses! I meant photodiode and have learnt now about a cool hack for phototransistor. Thank you!
